# Short story centered around a woman who lost her telepathic abilities, but can now help other telepaths survive

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Sorry, that title is terrible but this is hard story to sum up. I read this short story sometime in the 80s, likely out of my dad’s extensive library of SF.  What I can remember:

I believe the setting is Earth.  Humans have evolved into a telepathic society. The story focuses on a woman who was born a very highly ranked telepath but lost that ability through a tragedy. Usually death is the result, but in a few special cases when they survive they gain a rare and invaluable talent: the ability to save other telepaths who are also dying because of loss of their abilities. These special few live in an institutional setting, rarely allowed outside, and carefully watched because their risk of suicide is very high.

Some details of the protagonist: She lost her abilities because of her husband’s death.  He was kidnapped, drugged, and she refused to cut the link between them. The drug took days to kill him, but he couldn’t be located, and she spiraled down with him until the end, but did not die.  Now she lives in the institution, where friends smuggle in contraband—colorful scarves were mentioned.

A new technician comes to work for the institute but not directly with survivors; for some reason I keep thinking his name is Andy.  I don’t recall the circumstances but she meets him and he takes an interest in her.

She and the other survivors are called in for an emergency meeting for a teenager who suffered an injury, lost his abilities and is dying.  There is an older resident who is the lead on these emergencies, I believe it was mentioned he was from Asia, China maybe.  He and the woman occasionally slept together.  He insisted on helping the boy himself, which involved linking telepathically and trying to stop the mind’s death spiral.  She objected strongly because she knew how much he wanted to die.  She was overruled by whoever runs the facility, and the man links with the dying teen and refuses to unlink even when it’s obvious the teen won’t make it. The man ends up dying with the teen.

I think around this point she argues with the new tech, Andy, about all the survivor’s chances of suicide—how she could be dead tomorrow and that’s what she really wants.  Andy calls bullshit.  Later that night, the woman has slept with Andy and has a nightmare about the death of her husband.  Andy wakes, bundles her up, rocks her, sings or hums to her, helps her through, and she tells him he needs to be reassigned to their (the survivors) unit because he’s really good at this.

That’s about all I can remember. I thought for the longest time it was an Anne McCaffrey story, because of her Pegasus series, but I couldn’t find it in any of the books I have.  I hope someone can dig this up for me because it’s really stuck in my head.